# Steam Launch Segfault on Arch (steam.sh line 704)

Tags: segmentation-fault

Launching Steam on Arch Linux crashes with the error:

```
/home/matthew/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 704: 4013 Segmentation fault (core dumped) 
$STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$/PLATFORM$/STEAMEXE" "$@"
```

Started around when I switched from `xf86-video-ati` to `catalyst` and `lib32-catalyst-utils`

Comment: Can you try running it with `STEAM_RUNTIME=1` (so `STEAM_RUNTIME=1 steam` in `bash`-like shells)? It may not help, but this forces steam to use the builtin libraries instead of the system ones.

Comment: No dice, I've tried with both enabling and disabling STEAM_RUNTIME.

Comment: Can you get a backtrace? (Run trough `gdb`, then `bt full` and share the result, perhaps by adding it to the question) It would at least tell where is it crashing. Perhaps steam installs video driver-specific components on the first run? (After all, steam *is* a package manager.)

Comment: Do you know where the STEAMEXE is? /usr/lib/steam only has bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz